# Is there any library similar to conio.h?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu

I installed codeblocks and I wanted to make a program that reads keystrokes instantly, without me having to press enter. I did that when I was using the dev c + + on windows, but now I'm using Ubuntu and Codeblocks was the best IDE I found and it does not have the library . Can anyone tell me if there is something like conio, and if so, how to install?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linux alternative to `conio.h` is ncurses library. To install it search for packages: `libncurses`, `libncurses-dev`.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev`

Comment: @Patterson Please accept the answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: @Nazar554, it might be good to let others (that arrive at this topic) also know about `PDCurses` too; it is a library that provides Curses for many systems, including Windows. (In other words, `conio.h` only works in Windows, but Curses is available everywhere; you might have to include one free library at most.)